# How do I determine the time needed to open the big file (20MB)?

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

We are working on Universal Windows Apps in which we are opening the files (whose size is 20MB) using below code.

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".abc");
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file == null) return false;
    FlowSheetFilePath = file.Path;

LaunchQuerySupportStatus status = await Launcher.QueryFileSupportAsync(file);
if (status == LaunchQuerySupportStatus.Available)
{
    bool didLaunch = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);                               
    if (didLaunch)
    {
    }
}
```

In the above code, Is there any way to determine how much time is needed to completely open the file whose size is around 20MB?

Comment: That does not mean anything.  The true cost of reading a file is reading its content.  "Opening" just requires the OS to find the file.  Since it already did, FileOpenPicker did that job, the directory entry is hot in the file system cache and the operation is a fraction of a millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Note that this will depend not only on device configuration/type but ola CPU overload and so on.

If your app read/processes the file you may implement some kind of *ProgressBar* that will indicate how much work is already done (with implementation of *IProgress<>*) and how much is left, however that also won't help you with determination of time - you can think of estimating the time left basing on that what is already done, but this is only estimation and will surely change over time. But this won't also help you with *Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file)*.